# Zoom to and highlight search result in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, zoom

I have a function to search from layer. I got the desired results, so I want to zoom-in and highlight the results I found. How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
var sothuaMap = document.getElementById('sothuaMap');
    var sotoMap = document.getElementById('sotoMap');
    var phuongMap = document.getElementById('phuongMap');
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search');
    var resultSpan = document.getElementById('span');

    function search(sothuaGet, sotoGet, phuongMap) {
        resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Searching...';
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/vietnam/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=vietnam%3Ahtgovap&maxFeatures=50000&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&q=' + sothuaGet)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function (json) {
            var results = json.features;
            // console.log(results);
            if (results && results.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    const result = results[i];
                    if(result){
                        var props = result.properties; //get properties
                        var geom = result.geometry; //get geometry

                        var sothua = props.shthua;
                        var soto = props.shbando;
                        var phuong = props.xaphuong;
                        var dientich = props.dientich;
                        var coordinate = geom.coordinates;
                        if(sothua == sothuaGet && soto == sotoGet &&  phuong == phuongMap){
                            setProjection(sothua,soto,dientich,coordinate);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // setProjection(null, null, null);
          });
      }

    function setProjection(sothua, soto, dientich, coordinate){
        //
        if(sothua == null || soto == null){
            resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Not found, try again...!'
            return
        }
        resultSpan.innerHTML = 'ST: ' + sothua  + ' ' 
                                + 'SHBD: ' + soto +' '
                                + 'DT: ' + dientich + '<br>' 
                                + 'Geom: ' + coordinate;    
    }

    searchButton.onclick = function (event) {
        if(sotoMap.value != '' && sothuaMap.value != '' && phuongMap.value != ''){
            search(sothuaMap.value, sotoMap.value, phuongMap.value);
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            alert('Input data empty!');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
```

"Highlight" the same this:

[image]

Comment: I suppose final result is displayed with `setProjection` function, so zoom should happen there. Is this correct? Also what do you mean by "highligh result"? Please edit your question and add info about that.

Comment: Yes, that right! Result is displayed at `setProjection` function. I mean `highlight` means make it stand out

Comment: For highlighting the feature you need one of two things: (1) either some property in returned search result by which you can identify feature on the map and change it's style (2) or search result must contain geometry with which you create highlighted feture ans show it on the map.

Comment: How can I do that, can you give me an example? And I also want to zoom in to the highlighted feature. Thanks you.

Comment: Thee response from the WFS is a GeoJSON.  You can parse it to add the geometry to the map and zoom in on it https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-9yqzh5?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks @Mike, it works perfectly. Can you post it as answer so I can accepted it? Please. Thanks you again!